# Cut a window with a triangle shape from top most right corner

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, user-interface

We have two windows out of which one window is a small triangular shaped window used to display with a certain size in triangular format on top most right corner of desktop.

The 2nd window is a full screen mode window (Maximized window).

So, my requirement says that the 2nd window should be displayed in full screen mode such that it does not hide the 1st triangular window. I have the liberty to cut the full screen window size up to the size of triangular window.

PS: I can not use the TOP_MOST window property to always display triangular window on top of screen.

Attached: An expected window layout:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us coding attempts that you've already made? What ways have you considered going about doing this?

Comment: Take a look at SetWindowRgn function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: And Clipping might also be useable here.

Comment: @icbytes: And how would you set up non-rectangular clipping without calling [`SetWindowRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102.aspx)?

Comment: I wanted to add Clipping additionally ( if someone would like to place another image on his/her not-rectagled window. It was no either or comment.